# I want to learn how to create 3D games using Blender and Godot. First Step would be what steps would I need to create a universe?

Tags: modeling

Have basic understanding of Scenes and Nodes. 
Things I want to have are:
Black Hole (The Center of my Creation, I hope)
Constellations (Which I plan to orbit around the Black Hole)
Stars or Suns (Which I plan to orbit around the Black Hole)
Planets (Which I plan to orbit around Stars or Suns)
Dead Planets (Planets which do not have atmosphere)
Live Planets (Which have atmosphere and can support life)
Asteroid Belt (Which I plan to orbit around Stars or Suns)
Moons (Which I plan to orbit Planets)
Space Stations (To orbit anything or on the surface of a Planet or moon)
Ships to travel
Playable Characters
and Playable Characters.
Knowing this is more on the Basics, I just need to get a general idea on how to do many of these items or objects and make templates for adding others simply.
Like adding new start from a list of star types, and the same with planets, moons and space stations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to make a game, and really you just want to make some assets.  I'm not sure this it's possible to really answer the high level of complexity here but I can give you some overviews.

LOD is Level of Detail, and it means that you create at least three versions of a planet (Or any other object): A small four point plane with an image mapped to it for when you are too far away to care what it looks like, a low poly sphere with a texture mapped onto it for medium range, And a high detail version which includes multiple sphere's with transparency set on the outer spheres to represent clouds and atmospheres.

Use camera cuts to show show them landing on the surface, and then load up an area with natural boundaries to keep them contained in that area.

As for your universe and the planetary systems, there are quite a lot of ways to accomplish this.  I'm just going to suggest A way.

Create a few basic models of planets and moons together as groups.  Parent them to an empty object at the center of your planets.  Add Array modifiers to the moon to get more than one moon. Use drivers on the rotation of the empty to rotate the moons, and a driver on the moon to turn the base moon. Try playing with array modifiers stacked on array modifiers.

Once you have some variations of planets, you create a subdivided plane and add particles to it.  The particles can be groups and you can add your planet groups to the particle field.  Make sure you use the outline view of the plane to turn rendering of the plane off.  You can add more planes with different geometry to cluster or distribute other planet groups.  Remove geometry in the center of your plane to make room for the black hole.

Use a very large sphere UV mapped with stars with the normals flipped inside to represent deep space.

Use the camera depth to trigger your LOD detail for the planets and moons.

Assuming this is for a game, you CAN use the blender game engine, but you should probably leave it to Unity or the Unreal Engine (UE4) for the actual game environment.

Comment: That is a lot of good info. Yes I am thinking of video game ideas. I was a Chef in the Navy for 15 years and Excell and VB are about the only things I've been good with (without training). I downloaded Godot last week and starting to make scene of things. I am trying to make a map like https://www.hdri-hub.com/hdrishop/hdri/space/item/757-hdr-180-2-space-sky-and-stars but have no clue how.